# View QML SQLite database in a database browser

Tags: sql, database, qt, sqlite, qml

I created a database using Qt QML (QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0) and it is based on the SQLite. I then downloaded "SQLite Database Browser", but it is unable to open the database.

If anyone has a solution for this or can suggest a different viewer it would make debugging and creating tables easier.

I tried to create a database using SQLite Database Browser, then provided the .ini file that Qt needs and used Qt.md5(DataBaseName) to get the hash I needed to able to find the database using LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync().

I was able to open the database, but I could not find tables created with SQLite Database Browser. I was able to create a new table and read and write from it fine though.

My goal is to have a browser to view my tables and data to make the development easier and any solution is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you got the name of the database wrong. Have a look at the code in .../Src/qtdeclarative/src/imports/localstorage/plugin.cpp and look for md5. You could also use the "hello.qml localstorage" example and replace the database name in the example ("QQmlExampleDB") with your specific name and check which database file it creates. It is created in the user specific application data directory (in Windows7 it is C:\Users\yourloginname\AppData\Local\Qt Project\localstorage\QML\OfflineStorage\Databases). The database filename for "QQmlExampleDB" is "f684dc9fddfdbaf0a28e3664c61b27c9.sqlite". I could read this file with SqliteBrowser-3.2.0 and with the Firefox Addon "Sqlite Manager".

Comment: I have changed the offline path and can confirm that I have the correct name. I will check what version of SQLite Browser I got. I am running Qt 5.3.1, what about you?

Comment: I did exactly as you said and used the example and it works :)